# Iterate enumerated class instances

Tags: ceylon

Is there a simple way to iterate over all enumerated instances of a class in Ceylon?

Just like `values()` for Java enums?

```
abstract class Suit() of hearts | diamonds | clubs | spades {
    shared formal String name; 
}
object spades extends Suit() { name => "Spades"; }
object clubs extends Suit() { name => "Clubs"; }
object diamonds extends Suit() { name => "Diamonds"; }
object hearts extends Suit() { name => "Hearts"; }
```

Lets say I'd like to pick a random suit or I'd like to print all suits by their names.

**Edit:**

Explicitly adding all suits to an iterable works but we have to list all possible values again.

```
{Suit+} suits = {spades, clubs, diamonds, hearts};
```

Can somebody come up with something better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done now with [`ClassOrInterface.caseValues`](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/commit/966c97d90d109abdf6f31ab26faf993b8dff6742#diff-1):

```
Suit[] suits = `Suit`.caseValues;
```

Regarding the [returned sequence](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/issues/329#issuecomment-41277575):

> This sequence is ordered and skips any case type to only include case values.

Comment: Just for the record, this wasn't available until recently. Thanks to the ceylon team for adding this!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the metamodel:

```
for (caseType in `class Suit`.caseTypes) {
    assert (is OpenClassOrInterfaceType caseType);
    print(caseType.declaration.name);
}
```

Comment: Note: I opened [this issue](https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon.language/issues/329).

Comment: I've already come this far by myself. But as you mentioned in the issue it would be nice to get the instances. Thanks for your investigation.