# Iterating over enumeration values

Tags: enums, ceylon

Say I have this enum in Ceylon:

```
abstract class Suit()
        of hearts | diamonds | clubs | spades {}

object hearts extends Suit() {}
object diamonds extends Suit() {}
object clubs extends Suit() {}
object spades extends Suit() {}
```

I would like to iterate over the values. In Java, I would do `Suit.values()`. Is there something similar in Ceylon?

I tried to define it my self, but that didn't work because there are no static members in Ceylon? Should I just define at the top level:

```
Suit[4] suites= [hearts, diamonds, clubs, spades];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402031/ceylon-iterate-enumerated-instances

Comment: I am at a loss as to how that question did not come up in my searches as it is as duplicate as any question could possibly be. Embarrassingly identical...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (suit in `Suit`.caseValues) {
    // ...
}
```

[Try online](https://try.ceylon-lang.org/?gist=c95d0407adfaa6233425)

Note: since this uses the metamodel, it’s somewhat slow – certainly not as fast as `Enum.values()`. Cache the result if you’re going to use it a lot.